# Is there any function in aws redshift to find out the second largest record ?? or if no function what and how to find out the 2nd largest record?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, subquery, amazon-redshift

```
select * 
from peb_gateway_info pgi 
order by 'name' desc limit 1,1;
```

[image]

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Hint: there is a hint in your screenshot.

Comment: I'd expect `order by 'name' desc` to make no ordering at all, since the literal `'name'` is constant. Try `order by name desc` instead.

Comment: I was unknown about the offset functiion in PostgreSQL.. now I have got my answer.. Thanks @everyone for helping me .. :)

Answer (score 1):

using offset ?

```
select * 
from peb_gateway_info pgi 
order by name desc limit 1 offset 2;
```